# Failure to reload from checkpoint directory

Tags: spark-streaming, reload, illegalargumentexception, checkpointing

When I tried reloading my spark streaming application from a checkpoint directory, I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Checkpoint directory does not exist: maprfs:/mapr/cellos-mapr/user/mbazarganigilani/checkpoints/22237996-da79-4f13-b142-3ab112b7c374/rdd-1009
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD.<init>(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$checkpointFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1226)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$checkpointFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1226)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.checkpointFile(SparkContext.scala:1225)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData$$anonfun$restore$1.apply(DStreamCheckpointData.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData$$anonfun$restore$1.apply(DStreamCheckpointData.scala:109)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData.restore(DStreamCheckpointData.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.restoreCheckpointData(DStream.scala:515)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$restoreCheckpointData$2.apply(DStream.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$restoreCheckpointData$2.apply(DStream.scala:516)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.restoreCheckpointData(DStream.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$restoreCheckpointData$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$restoreCheckpointData$2.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:151)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.restoreCheckpointData(DStreamGraph.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$getOrCreate$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:864)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$getOrCreate$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:864)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate(StreamingContext.scala:864)
    at UnionStream$.main(UnionStreaming.scala:636)
    at UnionStream.main(UnionStreaming.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to override this exception for example something like reloading from previous checkpoint data?

Comment: Was any data deleted from the checkpoint directory?

Comment: I have not deleted any previous data.it may not write the chekpoint directory properly..or due to the network problem..

Comment: It could be also due to reloading from a checkpoint directory by a context which didn't write the checkpoint data properly..I encounter the above error after several reloading from the checkpoint data..

Comment: please post your code , how are you loading from check pointing directory